# Getting g++ error when installing R code from source

Tags: r, rcpp

I've downloaded Rcpp from CRAN and unzipeed it and attempted to build it. When I try to use R CMD INSTALL . in the directory I get:

```
cp: unknown option -- )
```

If I try to open up a session and use install.packages("Rcpp", type = "source"), I get the following error from `g++`:

```
*** arch - x64
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-30~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
Date.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
```

I have Rtools installed, and its directories are in the front of my path. I am on 64-bit Windows 7. Are there install options that I am missing? I have been reading appendix D of R's Installation and Administration manual and can't find anything I might have violated, everything was installed through Rtools. I feel like there is a flag that I am not including but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I'm afraud it's still your setup as in your previous question(s) -- the CRAN winbuilder happily builds Rcpp from source.

Comment: I've been having the same issues with Rtools, and both R3.01 and R2.15. Frustrating. I tried compiling it because Python don't seem to like the original dlls - so they should be compiled with the same compiler as the Python compiler - no luck. Windows 7 64-bit as like you.

Comment: @Trevor see my answer, I have no idea which one of these fixed the issue, but I will list the things that I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem started working once I did the following (I'm not sure which one fixed it) listed in consecutive order:

-threw my coffee cup against the wall, cursing Dirk Eddelbuettel

-changed the R path variable from C:R\R-3.0.1\bin to C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\

-reinstalled Rtools, this time checking the box allowing it to change the system path, I had been changing my user path before

-asked the spirit of Dirk Eddelbuettel for forgiveness

-restarted Rstudio

It worked. I think it was because I was not considering the system path, which is read first in windows, and so it was running into a Haskell g++ compiler, which was in front of everything, and only 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you, Mike!  This was causing me a lot of pain.  Changing the path variable did the trick.

Comment: I was using the wrong version of gcc. I had the one from MinGW (4.5.something) in my PATH set before gcc from Rtools (4.6.3). Once I removed the version that comes with MinGW, the compilation process went fine.

Comment: @Mike Flynn would you elaborate on "changed R path variable"?    I tried changing the PATH variable, but it didn't help.

Comment: what was the change you made? I think the difference for me was switching to the 64-bit version of the R executable in bin/x64/ rather than the standard in bin/

Comment: Which version of Dirk Eddelbuettel's spirit did you ask for forgiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Platform: Windows 7 64 bit

R version: 3.1.2

Rtools: Rtools32 windows binary

At least on my windows box, installing Rtools does not add the relevant values to the PATH Environment variable. To manually set the relevant values of your PATH environment variable, do the following:

(Click "Windows Icon --> right click "Computer" --> choose "Properties" --> Click "Advanced System Settings" --> click "Environment Variables" --> choose "PATH" and click "Edit" --> add the following to the PATH variable)

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;

1. Make sure no spaces in between path values
2. Failing to specify gcc directory (as in C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;) will spit the error "g++ not found"

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where my package installs were failing in RStudio because it couldn't find g++.exe. I had installed RTools on a different drive (D:) from my Windows 7 (64-bit) system files (C:). Even though my environment variables were correctly set to point to D, it kept looking for the RTools executables in C. I figured that RStudio was hardcoded to look at [System] which is C. I looked into moving it to D, but it appeared to be more hassle than it was worth (Microsoft stated that it would prevent future upgrades). I wound up reinstalling RTools on the C drive and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party -- but I just ran into this error. Another cause is that you are attempting to install the macOS binary of a package archive. You may need to find the source archive or the Windows binary.