# Publish an R code in github

Tags: github, git-branch, github-pages

I have written some codes in R that I have compiled into a package. Unfortunately
I am not able to publish it as a package such that any user may download it with the 
install_github() function.
Kindly help.

I have shared the path for the repository below.

https://github.com/Kagereki/RPerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to install your package I get the following error:

> Error: Line starting 'Population-Based Sur ...' is malformed!

The [specification for `DESCRIPTION` files](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) states that

> `DESCRIPTION` uses a simple file format called DCF, the Debian control format. You can see most of the structure in the simple example below. Each line consists of a **field** name and a value, separated by a colon. When values span multiple lines, they need to be indented:
>
> ```
> Description: The description of a package is usually long,
>     spanning multiple lines. The second and subsequent lines
>     should be indented, usually with four spaces.
> ```

Inspecting [your `DESCRIPTION` file](https://github.com/Kagereki/RPerio/blob/bc21921d4740f1532bcd3d6ae88b31d771a85f33/DESCRIPTION) shows that [its Description field](https://github.com/Kagereki/RPerio/blob/bc21921d4740f1532bcd3d6ae88b31d771a85f33/DESCRIPTION#L8-L15) is indeed formatted incorrectly, with the second line not indented:

```
Description: A collection of tools for Case Definitions and prevalences in 
Population-Based Surveillance of Periodontitis. 
  The functionality is experimental and functions are likely to ...
```

Note that this line begins with "Population-Based Sur ...", as suggested by the error message.

Make sure your `DESCRIPTION` is properly formatted and see if that fixes things.

You should be able to use the `check()` function from `devtools` to make sure that everything is working locally before you push up a new version.

Comment: Thanks for that Chris.I have edited that and it seems that was the main problem. However on trying to make the installation there seems there is still a problem : "cp: unknown option -- )"                           I would appreciate if you would have a look at it....

Comment: @ Chris. Yes am running on windows.

Comment: @Edwin, do you get any other errors? Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114308/getting-g-error-when-installing-r-code-from-source) help?

Comment: Now its running well. I appreciate that.